# php - APC memory caching for a large array variable (22MB)

Tags: php, caching, apc

I have a large 2D array that I serialized to be stored in a file.  The serialized file is about 9.5MB and takes about .05 seconds to read from disk.  To access the array, the unserialize process takes about 1.3 seconds, which is too long.

What I want to do is to unserialize the array first and then store that array as an APC cache variable.  I am running into a problem of having a server time out/not found error when I use `apc_store` or `apc_add`.   If I comment out the apc_store code, then it would be fine but then the array is not cached.  I have no problem with caching smaller test files/array of around 1MB.  From my php code below, I found that the memory size of the array in question is about 22MB.

These are my apc settings in the php.ini

```
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 512M
apc.ttl = 7200
apc.user_ttl = 7200
apc.num_files_hint = 1024
apc.enable_cli = 1
apc.max_file_size = 512M
apc.stat=1
```

I am testing my code on a local machine setup using xampp. Could anyone suggest how I can fix/get around this problem of server timing out?

Here is just my cache testing routine:

```
$startunser = microtime(true);

if ($quote = apc_fetch('serialfile')) {

        echo "<br> serfile [cached] ";
} 
else {

    $start_memory = memory_get_usage();
    $sF = "seri.txt";
    $sxx = file_get_contents($sF);
    $pro = unserialize($sxx);
    apc_store('serfile', $pro, 10);

    echo "<br>serfile is NOT cached ";
    echo memory_get_usage() - $start_memory;
}

$elapsedunser = microtime(true) - $startunser;
echo "<p>The unserialize process took $elapsedunser seconds";

return;
```

Also as an interesting side note for anyone's curiosity, when I recall (using apc_fetch) an array from APC that was unserialized from a serialized file of approximately 1MB, the fetch process actually was longer than just reading the file from disk and unserialize the file (.5 vs .4 seconds).  I did not believe that at first either.

TIA

Comment: just sounds wrong to have variables this large in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

APC isn't really suitable for storing data that large. Have you tried serialising the data as PHP code (using [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), for example), and writing it out as a .php file to be included in?  That might still be too large to handle though.